# datetime2 truncate to the last full 30 minute period

Tags: sql-server, datetime2

I'm trying to create a function that's rounding off to the last completed 30 minute period. My definition of a 30 minute period is every hour and half hour (12, 12:30, 13, 13:30, etc.)

So if the time is `22:16` I would like it to truncate to `22:00` however, if the time is `22:48` I would like the result to be `22:30`.

I have sofar tested:

```
DECLARE @RUN_DATE datetime2(1) = GETDATE();
DECLARE @Rounded datetime2(1) = dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, dateadd(mi, 0, @RUN_DATE)), 0)
```

However, this rounds `22:38` to `23:00`

Any tips are highly appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following trick

```
DECLARE @RUN_DATE datetime2(1) = GETDATE();
DECLARE @Rounded datetime2(1) = DATEADD(mi, DATEDIFF(mi, 0, @RUN_DATE)/30*30, 0)
select @rounded
```

Comment: This is brilliant. For my own sanity I just validated it with `DECLARE @RUN_DATE datetime2(1) = '2021-04-29 23:10:00.0';`and it returned `23:00`as expected. Thank you!